# Kids movie. Two friends set their wrist watches / alarms to remember to watch a TV show. One goes into the past and uses his watch battery to get help

Tags: story-identification, movie

I been trying to find the title of the movie involving these 2 scenes and the best description from what I can remember.
I can’t  think who the 2 kids I think both are male and have a watch alarm set to watch a specific tv show.
But I am thinking pretty sure came out in the 90s and had to do with time travel somehow to the past. Only one of the friends goes back not sure how.

So I only remember parts involving a wrist watch. First in the beginning two friends both have a wrist watch alarm set to remind them both to watch the same TV show. Then when one of the friends that goes into the past, his alarm goes off on his watch to remind him to watch the TV show but somehow helps by getting an idea using the watch battery.

The watch didn’t cause the time traveling only that the battery of the watch was used in the past after traveling there.

Both friends that had a alarm that set for both friends to watch a specific tv show

But can’t find those scenes when I think I am close to finding the movie the scenes aren’t there and I kept thinking it’s *A Kid in King Arthur’s Court* but something like that kind of movie feel.

Yea kind of but it has more a 90s feel. It’s not clockstoppers is slowing down time.